# Jquery Cycle Plugin Question - turning off relative links to photos so it goes to a URL

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I am using Jquery Cycle Plugin and it has a side panel that highlights as the photos change and currently when I click on the text the associated photo pulls up then I have to click on the photo to go to the URL but I would like the text itself to link to the URL. I have looked at the fn.cycle.defaults but not sure what to change and I tried a few things but nothing works. If anyone can help me figure this out it would be most helpful. Here are the fn.cycle.defaults:

```
fx:           'fade', // one of: fade, shuffle, zoom, scrollLeft, etc
timeout:       4000,  // milliseconds between slide transitions (0 to disable auto advance)
continuous:    0,     // true to start next transition immediately after current one completes
speed:         1000,  // speed of the transition (any valid fx speed value)
speedIn:       null,  // speed of the 'in' transition
speedOut:      null,  // speed of the 'out' transition
next:          null,  // id of element to use as click trigger for next slide
prev:          null,  // id of element to use as click trigger for previous slide
prevNextClick: null,  // callback fn for prev/next clicks:  function(isNext, zeroBasedSlideIndex, slideElement)
pager:         null,  // id of element to use as pager container
pagerClick:    null,  // callback fn for pager clicks:  function(zeroBasedSlideIndex, slideElement)
pagerEvent:    null, // event which drives the pager navigation
pagerAnchorBuilder: null, // callback fn for building anchor links
before:        null,  // transition callback (scope set to element to be shown)
after:         null,  // transition callback (scope set to element that was shown)
end:           null,  // callback invoked when the slideshow terminates (use with autostop or nowrap options)
easing:        null,  // easing method for both in and out transitions
easeIn:        null,  // easing for "in" transition
easeOut:       null,  // easing for "out" transition
shuffle:       null,  // coords for shuffle animation, ex: { top:15, left: 200 }
animIn:        null,  // properties that define how the slide animates in
animOut:       null,  // properties that define how the slide animates out
cssBefore:     null,  // properties that define the initial state of the slide before transitioning in
cssAfter:      null,  // properties that defined the state of the slide after transitioning out
fxFn:          null,  // function used to control the transition
height:       'auto', // container height
startingSlide: 0,     // zero-based index of the first slide to be displayed
sync:          1,     // true if in/out transitions should occur simultaneously
random:        0,     // true for random, false for sequence (not applicable to shuffle fx)
fit:           0,     // force slides to fit container
pause:         true,     // true to enable "pause on hover"
autostop:      0,     // true to end slideshow after X transitions (where X == slide count)
autostopCount: 0,     // number of transitions (optionally used with autostop to define X)
delay:         0,     // additional delay (in ms) for first transition (hint: can be negative)
slideExpr:     null,  // expression for selecting slides (if something other than all children is required)
cleartype:     0,     // true if clearType corrections should be applied (for IE)
nowrap:        0      // true to prevent slideshow from wrapping
};
```

I have tried changing the pageClick and pagerEvent but nothing seems to be working. Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the latest version of the plugin and you can set the 'allowPagerClickBubble' option to true.